# Node.js scraping, converting image src -> full URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, jsdom

I'm using Cheerio (https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) to scrape websites and get images for a project I'm working on.  I'm wondering if there's an easy way with Node.js (or another package) to convert the $(img).attr('src') to a fully qualified URL?  Sometimes I'll get "image.jpg" and other times "../../image.jpg", and other times "//somepath/image.jpg".  Perhaps I'm just missing a regex of some sort...  Thanks for your time :)

Comment: We will need the url of the scrapped site... Or an example of a site like that. Either way, I recommend you to build yourself an extra function to parse these values.

Comment: Ohh Brilliant !! I was troubled by the exact same thing, was manually writing out solutions for each of these. God bless SO !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the node [`url`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module. Specifically [`url.resolve(from, to)`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_resolve_from_to) should be what you're looking for.